# set web api route handler when using route attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom route handler witch i would like to use on different controllers. Right now the only way i get my controllers to use this route handler is to set it like this

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CustomRouteHandler",
    routeTemplate: "/custom/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
    ).RouteHandler = new CustomRouteHandler();
```

I would really like to use route attributes like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(Name = "GetCart")]
public Cart Get()
{
    return _repository.Get();
}
```

But when i'm using route attributes and can't seem to figure out how to make sure i use the custom route handler. Preferable i would only use route attributes so if i could use a attribute like "RouteHandler" and here point to my "CustomRouteHandler" that would be perfect.

Is there a attribute i can use like this or could i in some way point everything in a MapHttpRoute into "/Custom" and then use route attributes from here and make all controllers have the custom handler?

Another option could maybe to make my own attribute that foreces a controller or method to use my custom route handler?

I'm trying to make a really crystal clear way for the developer to see that this controller or method is using a custom routehandler and if new developers should add another controller they could just use a special route like "/custom" or use a attribute.

Any ideas are very welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: In the RouteConfig file, verify if you have setted the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`.

Comment: I do this by "config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();" - The routes are working, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in pure `AttributeRouting` due to some limitations:

> Beware! Due to integration issues with the Web API WebHost framework,
>   the following features will not work:
>
> performance enhancements when matching routes, custom route handlers,
>   querystring parameter constraints, subdomain routing, localization
>   applied to inbound/outbound urls, and lowercasing, appending prefixes,
>   etc to generated routes. These features all have to wait for vNext of
>   the Web API.

So you have only three options.

1) Make routing in `WebApiConfig.cs` in classic way:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetData",
    routeTemplate: "api/yourawesomecontroller/data",
    defaults: new { controller = "YourAwesomeController", action = nameof(YourAwesomeController.GetData) },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) },
    handler: new YourCustomMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
);
```

2) Also you may register `YourCustomMessageHandler` for all requests and implement route filtering inside handler itself:

```
class YourCustomMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Get &&
            request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/api/yourawesomecontroller/data"))

        // ... custom handling for request ...

        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // ... custom handling for response ...

        return response;
    }
}
```

3) The last option is a custom route attribute:

```
public class MyRouteAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public MyRouteAttribute (string url)
    {
        Url = url;
    }
}
```

which you need to decorate action methods with. But in this case you need to register routes like in option 1) in your custom bootstrapper like this:

```
foreach (var controllerType in allControllerTypes)
{
    var attributes = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(controllerType);
    var urlAttribute = (MyRouteAttribute) attributes[typeof(MyRouteAttribute)];
    var controllerName = controllerType.Name.Replace("Controller", "");

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: controllerName,
        routeTemplate: urlAttribute.Url,
        handler: new YourCustomMessageHandler() { InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config) }
    );
}
```

Note that you have to explicitly specify `InnerHandler` of `YourCustomMessageHandler` in order to pass requests down to pipeline to other handlers and controllers. See [Microsoft explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers#per-route-message-handlers) for details.

Comment: Option #2 worked best for me. I have a `ResponseHandler` for my Web API which I wanted only to work for any Url starting with `/api/`.