# How to add MessageHandler for a specific controller that is using Routing Attributes in ASP.NET WebAPI 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, message-handlers, routeattribute

It is possible to add a MessageHandler only for a specific controller that is using Route Attributes?

I want to cut the request earlier in the pipeline if it doesn't contain certain headers. I want to
   mention that:

- I can't add another route in WebApiConfig, we must use the Routing    Attributes from the controller.
- I don't want to add the MessageHandler globally.
- It has to be a MessageHandler (early in the pipeline). We have    alternatives for this but we are trying to do this more efficient.

For example, I've decorated the controller with the following RoutePrefix: api/myapicontroller and one action with Route(""). (I know it is strange, we are selecting a different action based on querystring)

Then, I've added

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "CustomRoute",
        routeTemplate: "api/myapicontroller/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: null,
        handler: new myMessageHandler()  
    );
```

If I put this code before `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` the myMessageHandler is executing but I get this Message:

> No action was found on the controller 'myapicontroller' that matches
>   the request

If I put `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` first, the myMessageHandler is never executed but the my action inside myapicontroller is called.

Comment: [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) does the same but using `MapHttpRoute`. But that doesn't hold to `Attribute Routing` btw.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can not set any handlers via `AttributeRouting`. If you want to assign handler to specific routes you have to register it via `MapHttpRoute` only. Except you need to add your controller name in `defaults` section like in Ajay Aradhya's answer and remove `Route` attribute from your action, because you are allowed to register routes either with `Route` attribute or `MapHttpRoute` method, but not both at the same time.

Also note that you need to create pipeline, otherwise you handler will work but request will not hit the controller action.
See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542991/set-web-api-route-handler-when-using-route-attributes/48538714#48538714) on similar question for details.

Answer (score -1):

This article from [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) explains the same. At last they provide a way to have controller specific handlers.But thats for the conventional routing. I don't know if this helps you or not.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MyCustomHandlerRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/MyController/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyController", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(new HttpControllerDispatcher(config), new MyCustomDelegatingMessageHandlerA());
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your message but I use Routing Attributes so I will never get into this newly created route (Routing Attributes have an higher priority than conventional routing).

Comment: Yes. i ll look into it. ll let u know if i find anything.